# Why this response.end(callback) is called two times?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with node.js, where i see this res.end(callback) is not controlled. Please help me to get relevent answer.

```js
const http = require('http');
const body = ' Appending text';
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=> {
    
    
    res.write("Hello , I created my first server ");
    res.end(body,afterend)   
    
});

server.listen(2000);
console.log("server is up and  running at 2000");
function afterend(){
    console.log("response ended")
}
```

**console o/p:
server is up and  running at 2000
response ended
response ended

expected console o/p:
server is up and  running at 2000
response ended
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. Infact the it's not the callback that's being invoked twice. It's the createServer method. Most browsers make a call to grab /favicon.ico. The console.log with req.url will show you what's happening

```
const http = require('http');
const body = ' Appending text';
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('Who is getting called here', req.url);
    res.write("Hello , I created my first server ");
    res.end(body, afterend)
});

server.listen(2000);
console.log("server is up and  running at 2000");
function afterend() {
    console.log("response ended")
}
```

Comment: Thank u sharan, just now i too checked about favicon.ico and createServer... :)

Comment: :) Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you